# Linux using write command to communicate with other users

Tags: linux, communication

I am learning Linux and I am learning how to communicate with other users. I am using Ubuntu.

I already have an existing user, and when I try to use the command `write` to communicate with other user

```
write lex pts/5
```

an error pops out:

```
write: you are uid 1000, but your login is as uid 1001
```

I thought the shell will allow communication in different `uid`s, but it cannot?

Is there any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

change your UID to 1001

You don't have to create a new user account, promote it to admin, log out, log in to the new admin account, change your primary account's UID, log out, log in to your primary account then delete the new admin user just change your UID. ;)

You can boot into recovery mode (it's an option that appears when you start up your computer, or hold shift right after the BIOS messages complete). This will log you in a root session. Being logged in root and not your usual user account, you will be able to modify your UID.

Because the recovery mode only works in command line interface, once logged into a root session, you will have to:

Use BubbaJ's instructions to remount the root file system in read-write mode: `mount -o remount,rw /.`
Use Luis Alvarado's command: `usermod -u NEW_UID your_username.`
Follow ddeimeke's instructions to update file permissions.
Then, reboot your computer (reboot), so you can boot in normal mode.